# Windows 7 can ping Switch, but Windows XP can't

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, ping, gateway

Maybe this question has already been asked, but I can't seem to find it by using the search.

I got a little network where I've got my default gateway on 10.0.0.1 with a switch built in.
Then there is another switch (Zyxel Presitge 324) 10.0.0.2 with clients, connected to the 10.0.0.1 Switch. And another Switch (D-Link di-604) 10.0.0.3 with clients, connected to the 10.0.0.1 switch

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 /     \
Clients XP+7
```

On the 10.0.0.3 switch are a Windows 7 and a Windows XP Client. The Windows 7 client can ping all devices - that's fine. But the Windows XP can't ping either the 10.0.0.2 switch or the clients on this switch. There are no ACL, filters, firewall set. This is really strange. What could be the problem? I thought of something like that Windows XP can't handle the hops?

Comment: What's the IP-Adress of the XP system? Also a 10.0.0.x address? Are there any routes defined (try `route print`) for 10.0.0.x addresses on the XP system?

Comment: Windows XP (as 7) got a 10.0.0.* DHCP from 10.0.0.1
route print on both XP and 7 have no active routes. The only thing different is, that XP says it has a standard GW of 10.0.0.1

Comment: none of the devices you have are pure switches, they're all firewall's/routers with switches built in; you then have a gateway (presumably with another firewall) that acts as your main router. Is this for a home setup and if so why so many high level attached devices instead of 1 main router with a bunch of 'dumb' switches? Just curious if any of the firewalls built in to your 'switches' could be causing some weirdness considering your setup..??

Comment: I know that these devices I use are not pure switches. I chose those because there is no reason for me to spend extra money on my infrastructure when all I need is already at home.